# How to conditional redirect after signIn without cancel session using next-auth

Tags: redirect, next.js, single-sign-on, next-auth

In my Next.js(App router) project I'm using next-auth with Google as provider for authentication.
After user successfully signIn(using default page for google authentication) I want to do a check if the user already visited the app. Depends on the result the user might be navigated to the page he was blocked earlier by the middleware or redirect to "first time seen" page.

**THE ISSUE**

nextAuthOptions signIn callback doesn't allow redirect **without cancelling the session**.
From the documentation: *"To redirect to a page after a successful sign in, please use the callbackUrl option or the redirect callback."*

Using the callbackUrl option is a good option - to redirect to a general url where I can check to which page redirect, BUT the signIn page is triggered by the default next-auth middleware and I can't specify the redirect page(as well as specific query params)

Redirect callback option -  callback is not called after the authentication with provider, and even if so, it does contain the props that signin callback has.

How can I make a custom redirect after successfully login?